# Softened logical implication using statistics

Tags: correlation, causality, logic

In a machine learning application, I have the following boolean implications $$\forall\,x,y:I_b(x,y)\rightarrow E_b(x,y),$$ where $I_b(x,y)$ being true means $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic, and $E_b(x,y)$ being true means that the distance between the embeddings generated by a model of $x$ and $y$ is zero.

Now, I want to soften this condition by introducing, $I(x,y)$ which is now a distance between $x$ and $y$ such that $I(x, y)$ is 0 when $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic, while the number is small and positive for "almost" isomorphic $x'$ and $y'$, and large and positive for other cases. I'll also introduce $E(x,y)$ which is just the $L_2$-distance between embeddings of $x$ and $y$. With this, I can still state that $$\forall\,x,y:\text{Low } I(x,y)\rightarrow\text{Low }E(x,y).$$ I have the values of $I(x,y)$ and $E(x,y)$ for all pairs of $x$ and $y$ in my dataset. How can I statistically verify that the above implication holds within my dataset.
I thought of using correlation, but correlation is symmetric while the implication is one-directional. Also, I know I have to do some sort of thresholding on $I(x,y)$ and $E(x,y)$ to make them booleans as well, but how does this thresholding value affect the truth of the implication? I have no clue how to approach this last question. I also plotted the values of $I_{\text{similarity}}(x,y)=e^{-I(x,y)}$ on x-axis and $E(x,y)$ on y-axis (because my colleague computed $I_{\text{similarity}}(x,y)$ instead of raw $I(x,y)$) and I should see negative correlation towards high values of $I_\text{similarity}(x,y)$ and $E(x,y)$, however I cannot understand the graph as of now.

Any direction towards solving this is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "statistically verify"?

Comment: From your above plot notice the right bottom corner, it seems only there your thesis holds with high *conditional probability* where the condition (antecedent) $I(x,y)$ approaches $0$ as your defined "Low" property while $E(x,y)$ approaches $0$ too  as your defined "Low" property, in the left region there's no clear conditional probabilistic distribution apart from uniform random with maximum entropy.

Comment: @whuber, what I mean is I only have the soft data. I want to verify the implication I mentioned that $\forall\,x,y:I(x,y)\rightarrow E(x,y)$.

Comment: @cinch, I did notice that. And I guess that is where it should hold from the loosely defined notion of "low". But how can I say this for sure, given the data?

Comment: There's nothing for sure in stats site here except via [statistical significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) used in H0 testing. Specifically after picking a reasonable thresholds for your "Low' properties after EDA, your I(x,y) is like KL-Divergence of 2 populations with different distributions, and your embedding distance E(x,y) is like the difference of 2 sample means from the 2 populations. Therefore you can compute the classic t-test statistic to try to keep the H0 as no sample means' difference so long as the 2 populations have KL-D within your threshold.

Comment: @cinch thanks for this. I have no experience with statistical testing. Is there an online resource to get started in identifying situations where a particular statistical test like this is applicable.